# Conditional RequireJs configuration (Load requirejs-config.js programmatically?)

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, overrides, requirejs, magento2.3

I would like to replace a RequireJs component only on certain conditions (for example, based on configuration). Is there any way to programmatically prevent loading of my module's `requirejs-config.js` or a different way to achieve it?

Comment: did you find the solution to this problem?

Comment: @stevensagaar unfortunately not

Comment: did you find the solution to this problem?

Comment: If I find one, I'll add an answer here

Comment: @FabianSchmengler Did you find one *now* :-) Are you still looking for magento-2.1? Maybe update the tags...

Comment: @Alex if there's a solution for 2.2 or 2.3 I'd be happy, too :D updated the tags. Also, thanks for the bounty!

Comment: Have you tried rewriting getConfig function in vendor/magento/framework/RequireJs/Config.php or you need to write plugins in requirejs https://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html

Comment: @FabianSchmengler Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 7):

Based on @Arshad M comment, you can add a di.xml with:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Framework\RequireJs\Config" type="<Vendor>\<ModuleName>\RequireJs\Config"/>

</config>
```

And in < Vendor >\< ModuleName >\RequireJs\Config.php override the getConfig function adding your condition and the module name that you don't want the requirejs to be loaded (probably from ScopeConfigInterface) :

```
   <?php

namespace <Vendor>\<ModuleName>\RequireJs;

use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\File\ReadFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Minification;
use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\RepositoryMap;

class Config extends \Magento\Framework\RequireJs\Config
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\RequireJs\Config\File\Collector\Aggregated
     */
    private $fileSource;
    /**
     * @var ReadFactory
     */
    private $readFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Code\Minifier\AdapterInterface
     */
    private $minifyAdapter;
    /**
     * @var Minification
     */
    private $minification;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface
     */
    private $design;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\RequireJs\Config\File\Collector\Aggregated $fileSource, \Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface $design, ReadFactory $readFactory, \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo, \Magento\Framework\Code\Minifier\AdapterInterface $minifyAdapter, Minification $minification, RepositoryMap $repositoryMap)
    {
        parent::__construct($fileSource, $design, $readFactory, $assetRepo, $minifyAdapter, $minification, $repositoryMap);
        $this->fileSource = $fileSource;
        $this->readFactory = $readFactory;
        $this->minifyAdapter = $minifyAdapter;
        $this->minification = $minification;
        $this->design = $design;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        $distributedConfig = '';
        $customConfigFiles = $this->fileSource->getFiles($this->design->getDesignTheme(), self::CONFIG_FILE_NAME);
        foreach ($customConfigFiles as $file) {
            //Your condition
            if(true){
                if($file->getModule() == "Vendor_ModuleName"){
                    continue;
                }
            }

            /** @var $fileReader \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\File\Read */
            $fileReader = $this->readFactory->create($file->getFileName(), \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverPool::FILE);
            $config = $fileReader->readAll($file->getName());


            $distributedConfig .= str_replace(
                ['%config%', '%context%'],
                [$config, $file->getModule()],
                self::PARTIAL_CONFIG_TEMPLATE
            );
        }

        $fullConfig = str_replace(
            ['%function%', '%usages%'],
            [$distributedConfig],
            self::FULL_CONFIG_TEMPLATE
        );


        if ($this->minification->isEnabled('js')) {
            $fullConfig = $this->minifyAdapter->minify($fullConfig);
        }

        return $fullConfig;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

After comments from @Alex and @Daniel:
You can make an after plugin for getFiles from Magento\Framework\RequireJs\Config\File\Collector\Aggregated , so the new di.xml with this approach would be:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Framework\RequireJs\Config\File\Collector\Aggregated">
        <plugin name="requirejsConfigPlugin"
                type="<Vendor>\<ModuleName>\Plugin\RequireJs\AfterFiles"
                sortOrder="100"
        />
    </type>
</config>
```

And at \< Vendor>\< ModuleName>\Plugin\RequireJs\AfterFiles, you can set your condition and module that the requirejs will not be load:

```
<?php

namespace <Vendor>\<ModuleName>\Plugin\RequireJs;

class AfterFiles
{
    public function afterGetFiles(
        \Magento\Framework\RequireJs\Config\File\Collector\Aggregated $subject,
        $result
    ){
        //Your condition
        if(true) {
            foreach ($result as $key => &$file) {
                //Module to exclude
                if ($file->getModule() == "Vendor_OtherModuleName") {
                    unset($result[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! I think we could improve that by $fullConfig = parent::getConfig() and then modify $fullConfig to copy&paste less code. What do you think? Maybe we should make a mini-FOSS-module on github for this?

Comment: Or can $this->fileSource->getFiles be rewritten instead? Just to not copy to much code ...

Comment: @Alex You could as well use a plugin and use an `aroundGetConfig()` or `afterGetConfig()` method in order to achive the conditional loading then we don't have to overwrite it

Comment: Looks promising, thank you! I already upvoted, will try it out asap before accepting the answer

Comment: @Alex following your suggestion I made a small module in github, where you can select the modules to disable the requirejs via magento backend. Check it out and maybe contribute 
https://github.com/MNGemignani/magento2_requirejs_disable

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work on a store-view level in Production mode :-( https://github.com/MNGemignani/magento2_requirejs_disable/issues/1#issuecomment-465033875